# Ошибка MSB3577: Два имени выходных файлов разрешаются в один и тот же выходной путь

Tags: .net, visual-studio, github

После скачивания проекта с `github.com` хочу запустить проект с помощью `Visual Studio`. Однако возникает следующая ошибка, связанная с файлами ресурсов `resx`:

> Ошибка MSB3577: "Два имени выходных файлов разрешаются в один и тот же
>   выходной путь: obj\Debug\xxx.resources".

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739794/two-output-file-names-resolved-to-the-same-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть еще один момент, который будет полезен тем, кто наступит на эти "грабли".

1. У меня данная ошибка возникла для решения, в котором ДВА варианта приложения с разными версиями библиотек
2. Я перетаскивал из одного решения в другое новую версию кода. При этом класс у меня был partial (!) то есть в двух файлах с кодом. При перетаскивании  (условное название) кода myclass который находится в двух файлах myclass.cs и myclass2.cs для файла myclass2.cs был АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ создан ПУСТОЙ файл ресурсов myclass2.resx. Именно ОН при линковке и генерирует такое чудесное сообщение
3. Решние: удаляем пустой файл ресурсов myclass2.resx и проект оживает

Comment: Да, наиболее частая проблема при такой ошибке - это два файла ресурса для одной формы

Answer (score 1):

**UPD.** Все же основная проблема была не в способе скачивания (хотя он также может быть причиной проблемы). Проблема в том, что данный проект запускается только под ОС `Windows 10` (как заявляют сами разработчики), в то время как я использовал `Win 7`. Это очень странно, учитывая то, что основной технологией разработки UI была WinForms. Да, там есть один проект, который использует UWP, но я его не включаю в построение сборки.

Также решением может быть то, что скачивать проект с `github.com` нужно через **git**, а не архивом. Если скачивать репозиторий как архив, то он не будет содержать в себе некоторых необходимых подмодулей репозитория.

**P.S.** странно, но я не нашел ответа на вопрос даже на англоязычном `stackoverflow`, поэтому считаю полезным опубликовать ответ на данный вопрос. Сам мучился с этой проблемой около трех часов.